# Wrap specific text with link Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using `Nokogiri` and haven't been able to figure out how to wrap a specific word with a link that I provide.

I have `<span class="blah">XSS Attack document</span>`

Which I want to change to

`<span class="blah"><a href="http://blah.com">XSS</a> Attack document</span>`

I know that there's a `.wrap()` in Nokogiri but it doesn't appear to be able to wrap just the specific `XSS` text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By explicitly creating and adding a new node

```
require 'nokogiri'

text = '<html> <body> <div> <span class="blah">XSS Attack document</span> </div> </body> </html>'
html = Nokogiri::HTML(text)

# get the node span
node = html.at_xpath('//span[@class="blah"]')
# change its text content
node.content = node.content.gsub('XSS', '')

# create a node <a>
link = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('a', html)
link['href'] = 'http://blah.com'
link.content = 'XSS'

# add it before the text
node.children.first.add_previous_sibling(link)

# print it
puts html.to_html
```

By using `inner_html=`

```
require 'nokogiri'

text = '<html> <body> <div> <span class="blah">XSS Attack document</span> </div> </body> </html>'
html = Nokogiri::HTML(text)

node = html.at_xpath('//span[@class="blah"]')
node.inner_html = node.content.gsub('XSS', '<a href="http://blah.com">XSS</a>')

puts html.to_html
```

The both solutions are ok in our case. But when traversing the node tree, `inner_html=` is not the best as it removes all the children nodes. Because it removes all node children, it's not the best choice in terms of performance, when what you need just to add a node child.

Comment: Thanks but `node.to_html` returns the link as `&lt;a href` is there a way to not convert it to html entities?

Comment: @Hengjie you're right, I've just fixed it. As `<a>` is a node, it is needed to create it and add it to the node `span` before the text.

Comment: Thanks @toch but would it also work if we simply set node.inner_html with the gsub result? Or are there unexpected consequences with that?

Comment: @Hengjie good question. Again, you're right, it works and ok in our case. But when you need to add a child node, it's not the best one (cf my explanation at the bottom).